Listings over multiple pages affects header style
I am currently using titlesec (which includes titleps) for my page formatting, and listings to format code.
Things worked out well until I entered a long piece of code which spans through multiple pages (the following is a simplified example of the phenomenon I am seeing)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=210mm,
    paperheight=80mm,
    includehead,
    includefoot,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=0.75in,
    headheight=3\baselineskip,
    showframe
]{geometry}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{main}{
    % set header
    \sethead{% odd-left
        \noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \mbox{Course name}\\
                \mbox{Course No.}\\
                \mbox{Instructor}
            \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}
    }{}{}
}
\pagestyle{main}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    lineskip=-0.5ex
}

\begin{document}
    Page with unintended header height.
    \begin{lstlisting}
        Hello, world!
        Hello, world!
        Hello, world!
        Hello, world!
    \end{lstlisting}
    Page with intended header height.
\end{document}


As shown in the example, the lineskips of headers of the pages containing the start and body of the code (but not the end of code) is tampered, presumably by the lineskip of the lstlistings environment. I want to find a workaround for this.
Maybe I can set a default lineskip for headers so that once TeX enters the header, it uses the default lineskip and restores the (altered) lineskip when typesetting of headers is done. I have not succeeded however.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

An explicit \linespread{1}\selectfont solves the issue:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=210mm,
    paperheight=80mm,
    includehead,
    includefoot,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=0.75in,
    headheight=3\baselineskip,
    showframe
]{geometry}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{main}{%
    % set header
  \sethead{% odd-left
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
      \linespread{1}\selectfont
      \begin{flushleft}
        \mbox{Course name}\\
        \mbox{Course No.}\\
        \mbox{Instructor}
      \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
  }{}{}%
}
\pagestyle{main}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    lineskip=-0.5ex
}

\begin{document}
    Page with unintended header height.
    \begin{lstlisting}
        Hello, world!
        Hello, world!
        Hello, world!
        Hello, world!
    \end{lstlisting}
    Page with intended header height.
\end{document}


Similar with scrlayer-scrpage instead of titleps:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=210mm,
    paperheight=80mm,
    includehead,
    includefoot,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=0.75in,
    headheight=3\baselineskip,
    showframe
]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[headsepline,headtopline,singlespacing]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{%
  \mbox{Course name}\\
  \mbox{Course No.}\\
  \mbox{Instructor}
}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    lineskip=-0.5ex
}

\begin{document}
    Page with unintended header height.
    \begin{lstlisting}
        Hello, world!
        Hello, world!
        Hello, world!
        Hello, world!
    \end{lstlisting}
    Page with intended header height.
\end{document}


or fancyhdr:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=210mm,
    paperheight=80mm,
    includehead,
    includefoot,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=0.75in,
    headheight=3\baselineskip,
    showframe
]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{%
    \mbox{Course name}\\
    \mbox{Course No.}\\
    \mbox{Instructor}
  }%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    lineskip=-0.5ex
}

\begin{document}
    Page with unintended header height.
    \begin{lstlisting}
        Hello, world!
        Hello, world!
        Hello, world!
        Hello, world!
    \end{lstlisting}
    Page with intended header height.
\end{document}


